# Terminal Errors when I open Browsers

Tags: command-line, firefox, google-chrome

When I open a browser in terminal (I've tried Firefox and Google Chrome) I get error messages.

When I open Firefox it spits out this:

```
Performance warning: Async animation disabled because frame size (2280, 97) is bigger than the viewport (2160, 1188) or the visual rectangle (2280, 97) is larger than the max allowable value (17895698) [div]

(process:2659): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
Vector smash protection is enabled.

(process:3433): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed

(process:3509): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed

###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x80000F,name=PHttpChannel::Msg___delete__) Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

And when I open chrome it spits out this one:

```
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
Vector smash protection is enabled.
```

After looking into both of these (and doing some experimentation) I couldn't find a solution, but it seems that this is a problem with flash and not html5. Also, this happens when I open firefox in safemode.

This hasn't caused me any (noticeable) problems yet, but it irks me that it is happening and I have no clue what's going on. To the best of my knowledge this problem wasn't happening last night when I last got online.

Lastly I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your browsers run as expected then the messages can safely be ignored. Generally they are intended for developers, not for end users, and provide information for debugging.

[Sandboxing](http://www.howtogeek.com/169139/sandboxes-explained-how-theyre-already-protecting-you-and-how-to-sandbox-any-program/) is a security feature. Chrome is restricting the actions of code from the site, for example not allowing it permission to read files on your computer.